# Left Join Without Eloquent Model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I wanted to left join Product and ProductPrice tables together, but my mentor said not to use the eloquent relationship. So here's the code he said to use:

This is a function in App\Http\Controllers\Api\ProductController.php that's using his custom left join:

```
public function table($dproduct, $start, $search, $sortColumn, $sort, $index, $limit)
    {
        $result['dproduct'] = $dproduct;
        $result['data'] = array();
        $result['recordsFiltered'] = 0;
        $result['recordsTotal'] = 0;

        $product = new Product();
        $productResult = $product->getResult($search, $sortColumn, $sort, $index, $limit);

        if ($productResult['Total'] > 0) {
            $result["recordsFiltered"] = $productResult['Total'];
            $counter = $start;

            $data = array();
            foreach ($productResult['Data'] as $productData) {
                $counter++;
                $data[] = $this->set($counter, $productData);
            }

            $result["recordsTotal"] = $counter;
            $result["data"] = $data;
        } else {
            $result["error"] = $productResult['Message'];
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

here's the actual ProductController(non-api):

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    const PRODUCT = 'product';

    public function __construct()
    {
        return parent::authenticate();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $admin = $this->getAdmin();

        $productView = $this->isView(ProductController::PRODUCT);
        $productCreate = $this->isCreate(ProductController::PRODUCT);
        $productUpdate = $this->isUpdate(ProductController::PRODUCT);
        $productDelete = $this->isDelete(ProductController::PRODUCT);

        if ($productView) {
            return parent::setCompactView(ProductController::PRODUCT, compact(
                'admin',
                'productView',
                'productCreate',
                'productUpdate',
                'productDelete'
            ));
        } else {
            return parent::setCompactView('error', compact('admin'));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\GlobalController;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Product';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    const CREATED_AT = 'CreatedDate';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'UpdatedDate';

    public function getAll()
    {
        return self::where('Active', true)->get();
    }

    public function getById($Id)
    {
        return self::where('Id', $Id)->first();
    }

    public function getResult($search = '', $sortColumn = 0, $sort = '', $page = 0, $limit = 0)
    {
        if ($sortColumn == 1) {
            $sortColumn = 'Description';
        } else {
            $sortColumn = 'Name';
        }

        if ($sort == '') {
            $sort = 'asc';
        }

        $data = self::where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            return $query->where('Name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('Description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
            ->skip(($page - 1) * 10)
            ->take($limit)
            ->orderBy($sortColumn, $sort)
            ->get();
        $count = self::where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            return $query->where('Name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('Description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })->get()->count();

        $result['Data'] = $data;
        $result['Total'] = $count;

        if ($count <= 0) {
            $result['Message'] = GlobalController::TEXT_NO_DATA;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        return self::get()->count();
    }

    public function setDelete($id)
    {
        return self::where('Id', $id)->delete();
    }
}
```

And here's my ProductPrice Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\GlobalController;

class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ProductPrice';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
}
```

ProductPrice doesn't have a controller yet as i don't really understand what to type in it.

The Product table has these as tables:

```
        Schema::create('Product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('Id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('CategoryId')->nullable();
            $table->string('Name', 60)->charset('utf8');
            $table->mediumText('Description')->charset('utf8')->nullable();
            $table->uuid('CreatedId')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('CreatedDate')->useCurrent();
            $table->uuid('UpdatedId')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('UpdatedDate')->useCurrent();
        });

        Schema::table('Product', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('CategoryId')->references('Id')->on('Category')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('CreatedId')->references('Uid')->on('Admin')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('UpdatedId')->references('Uid')->on('Admin')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```

and ProductPrice is this:

```
        Schema::create('ProductPrice', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('Id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('ProductId');
            $table->integer('Price')->default(0);
            $table->integer('CutPrice')->default(0);
            $table->integer('SpecialPrice')->default(0);
            $table->smallInteger('Discount')->default(0);
            $table->uuid('CreatedId')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('CreatedDate')->useCurrent();
            $table->uuid('UpdatedId')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('UpdatedDate')->useCurrent();
        });

        Schema::table('ProductPrice', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('ProductId')->references('Id')->on('Product')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('CreatedId')->references('Uid')->on('Admin')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('UpdatedId')->references('Uid')->on('Admin')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```

My question is, what do i need to do to left join them together on ProductId as foreign key then show them in my view on the same table view?

Comment: you can use `DB` query builder. i think that will help you.

Comment: Like this? $users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->get();

Comment: yes. that's it you can try